# Разрешение на создание порта с номером ниже 1000

Tags: linux

Как разрешить приложению или пользователю, создать UDP порт с номером ниже 1000 без прав суперпользователя.

Comment: не 1000, а 1024 только...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Права суперпользователя понадобятся для команды:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /home/user/bin/my_program
```

После чего пробуйте запускать свою программу.