# Разрешение на создание порта

Tags: linux

Ранее я [спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813182/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5-1000) как разрешить создание порта с номером ниже тысячи. Мне был дан ответ сделать так:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /home/user/bin/my_program
```

Это работает, программа может создавать порты, но проблема в том что эта команда, затирает `rpath`, что мне не подходит. Возможно есть еще варианты. Например разрешить всем эту привилегию.

Comment: можно вывод `objdump`'а до/после для подтверждения?

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Я наврал, секция `RPATH`,  остается. Но проблема то осталась. После применения этой команды, перестают находится зависимости. Возможно`RPATH` начинает игнорироваться.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi можно перенапрвлять порты ниже 1024 на более высокий уровеь через таблицу маршутризации, например. и тогда ваша программа не будет запрашивать доступ к порту >1024,  но при этом все будет работать

Comment: @Rikitikitavi, если верить [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843178/linux-capabilities-setcap-seems-to-disable-ld-library-path), то использование rpath — как раз workaround и не должен игнорироваться... с другой стороны понятно, почему различные переменные среды игнорятся... можешь mcve подготовить для экспериментов?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor Для этого мне нужно будет изменить исходный код программы и создавать не привилегированный порт, и потом через таблицу маршрутизации перенаправлять на новый порт?

Comment: @Rikitikitavi да, скажем, вы поднимаете все порты на +10000. тогда 22 порт будет 10022. и если ваша программа использует 22 порт, то просто измените на 10022. в системе перенаправьте все с 22 на 10022 и наоборот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот здесь](https://superuser.com/questions/1316398/are-there-any-ways-to-allow-create-privileged-port) мне ответили. Мне помог вариант с

```
net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start = 0
```

нужно дописать эту строку в файл `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Потом запустить `sysctl -p`.

Answer (score 0):

можно перенапрвлять порты ниже 1024 на более высокий уровеь через таблицу маршутризации, например. и тогда ваша программа не будет запрашивать доступ к порту выше 1024, но при этом все будет работать

Для этого нужно будет изменить исходный код программы и создавать не привилегированный порт.